# Unable to initiate the route from the beginning after else statement deadend

Tags: javascript, node.js

Firstly, I'm sorry if this has been posted before. I searched but couldn't find any credible solution.

So I'm working on this route in nodejs where I make an API call for a piece of information and then using that info in an if statement to check if it's the correct info(the server sometimes sends wrong info).

If I get the correct info then I use that in another API to get more info about it and render it into my template. Everything works fine.

But I want the first API call to take place again if the info doesn't match or it's wrong. How can I initiate the API call again from the start(like a loop) and it will break only if the info is correct.  Please check the "comment" in the code below. That is where I don't know what to put. Your help would be highly appreciated.

PS. I am a beginner in nodejs and javascript.

Route

```
router.get("/check", (req, res) => {
    if(req.query.search) {
        var input = req.query.search;
        var url = "http://firstapi.com/json/" + input + "?fields=query";
        request(url, function(error, response, body) {
            if(!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(body);
                if(data.query.match(/((^|\.)((25[0-5])|(2[0-4]\d)|(1\d\d)|([1-9]?\d))){4}$/)){
                    var url = "https://secondapi.com/" + data.query + "?key=something";
                    request(url, function(error, response, body) {
                        if(!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                            var Data = JSON.parse(body);
                            res.render("index", {data: Data});
                        }
                    });
                }else{
//want to use the input at the top and check the firstapi again. All the code above should run again until its the correct one which I will use in my template.
                }
            }
        });
    }else{
        res.render("index", {data: null});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do it this way:

```
router.get('/check', (req, res) => {
  if (req.query.search) {
    var input = req.query.search;
    // Put this logic away in a `checkData` function
    checkData(input)
      .then(data => {
        res.render('index', { data }); // Short version of {data: data}
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        res.render('index', { data: null });
      });
  } else {
    res.render('index', { data: null });
  }
});

// Here, we have a `retries` parameter, set to 0 initially
function checkData (input, retries = 0) {
  const maxRetries = 3;
  // Return a promise (you could also use callbacks)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Define a retry method
    const retry = () => {
      if (retries < maxRetries) {
        // Increment the retries count and go for another try
        checkData(input, retries + 1).then(resolve).catch(reject);
      } else {
        reject(`Could not get the data after ${retries} retries.`);
      }
    };
    var url = `http://firstapi.com/json/${input}?fields=query`;
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        if (data.query.match(/((^|\.)((25[0-5])|(2[0-4]\d)|(1\d\d)|([1-9]?\d))){4}$/)) {
          var url = 'https://secondapi.com/' + data.query + '?key=something';
          request(url, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
              var Data = JSON.parse(body);
              // If it worked, resolve with the data
              resolve(Data);
            } else {
              retry();
            }
          });
        } else {
          retry();
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Mate, you are a genius. That was awesome. Although the function is waayyyyy out of my league and went above my head but it works. I'll just learn it. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: There isn't really much to it, but I'm glad it helped :) A [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is just an alternative to callbacks. Except it can `resolve` with a value when it succeeds, and `reject` with an error when it fails. If it succeeds, it executes the function you have in `then`, otherwise, the one you have in `catch`. If you want, I could make a version which uses callbacks, but I encourage you to learn about Promises, in a lot of cases it will make your code more readable (chaining instead of wrapping)

Comment: No it's fine. That would be a lot to ask from you. You helped a lot already. Also, I think it'd be good if I can crack this code myself after I learn Promises and the other new features of JS. But can you recommend or suggest a platform where I can learn or practice advanced JS?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't use any platform, I learn every day when stumbling upon an article on Medium.com, getting feedback or reviewing code from colleagues, looking for ways to do stuff on StackOverflow, following tutorials on various sites I find on Google... Here is one which describes the [basics of Promises](https://codeburst.io/javascript-learn-promises-f1eaa00c5461)